# If $a$ has order $3 \pmod p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, show that $a+1$ must have order $6 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ has order $3 \pmod p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, show that $a+1$ must have order $6 \pmod p$

---

Since $3$ is the order of $a$ :
$a^3\equiv 1 \pmod p$

I am stuck after this. Not getting ideas. Any help ?

Comment: This is a fun one.  What happens when you consider $a^3-1\equiv 0\pmod p$?

Comment: Oh $a^3-b^3$ formula ?

Comment: $$(a-1)(a^2+a+1) \equiv  0 \pmod p$$  but I'm not so good with quadratic congruences. Need little more help :3

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463010/show-that-if-a-has-order-3-bmod-p-then-a1-has-order-6-bmod-p

Comment: Also [my question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666269/is-it-possible-to-solve-i2i1-equiv-0-pmod2p-1-in-general)...

Comment: thank you all so much for the very useful pointers, going through them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$a^3-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)=0\pmod p\stackrel{\text{since}\;a\neq 1}\iff a^2+a+1=0\pmod p\implies$$

$$a+1=-a^2=\pmod p$$

and from here

$$(a+1)^6=(-a^2)^6=a^{12}=(a^3)^4\pmod p\ldots$$

Comment: Note that you can use `\equiv` to produce $\equiv$ for the modular equivalence symbol

Comment: this looks simpler to follow :) thanks a lot !!